# Programmatically install an SSL certificate into a browser's store

Tags: go, firefox, certificate

I have an application written in Go which needs the web browser (ideally Firefox) to have a self-signed certificate installed.

Of course I can provide instructions to end users on how to install a certificate, but this is far from ideal.

Ideally, I want to programatically add the certificate - using a firefox API, command line, registry hack or some other approach.  Of course I would love a cross platform solution, but even windows only would be a start.

Comment: maybe this? You can use it with Let's Encrypt https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert - not sure it hits your specific use case, it is more for ssl things

Comment: @Slabgorb - no I don't think that helps - I have the certificates I need, the question is how to install these into the browser.

Comment: I'd start with comprehending https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA/AddRootToFirefox

Comment: It's going to vary by browser. It's probably easier to add a certificate to the OS' trusted certificate store.

Comment: @Adrian, I believe FF uses it's own store, independent of the OS.

Comment: It does, but it should treat that as supplementary to the OS' trusted certificates.

Comment: @kostix comment best so far - that wiki explains that "Since Firefox does not use the operating system's certificate store by default, these CA certificates must be added in to Firefox using one of the following methods." - but then shows how FF can be persuaded to look at the OS trusted certificates.  That might be the route..

Comment: The point of using letsencrypt is that you _don't need to install certs in the browser_.

Comment: @richp10, yes, your analysis is about 100% correct, but note that FF can be persuaded to look into the OS-specific cert store only on Windows. Linux-based platforms simply do not have one (most of them have an OpenSSL-specific system-wide one, also used by GNUTLS FWIW, but the "NSS" library used by FF to handle SSL/TLS-related stuff is not able to access it), and I honestly have no idea what the situation is on OS X platforms (I suspect there people tend to, ahem, think different and use what's preinstalled).

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to this but you *can* programmatically add self-signed or untrusted root certs to FireFox that are distribution wide (not tied to any user's browser). Here's what I got to work on Ubuntu 18.04 with FireFox 85.0:

1. Add the cert (with .crt extension in PEM format) to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates or /usr/share/ca-certificates. Either is fine but you need to update the install location in JSON below.
2. `sudo update-ca-certificates`
3. Create this json file: `/usr/lib/firefox/distribution/policies.json` with the code below

```
{
    "policies": {
        "Certificates": {
            "ImportEnterpriseRoots": true,
            "Install": [
                "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/<$NAMEOFYOURCERT.crt>"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You could really skip steps 1/2 and point the Install location in the policies.json file to wherever the cert is located but this ensures your OS trusts the cert too, not just FireFox.

Pretty simple to script these instructions into a bootstrap script for OS installs or a one-off script to hand to users to run if you trust them.