How to upload a ssl certificate into google chrome webdriver in selenium python
I need to use selenium python with an uploaded personal security certificate every time my service launch a new process, and for some reason is not possible to click at import in the Google Chrome settings.
I try to use XPATH, ID and other By options, and no way to work. If anyone has experience with this type of problem, would appreciate the help.
The error that mostly happen is

File "", line 2, in 
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="import"]')))
File "/home/pc/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 105, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Any help will be highly appreciated!
My code
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
import os

def create_webdriver_chrome(download_dest):

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    prefs = {
        "download.default_directory": download_dest,
        "download.directory_upgrade": True,
        "download.prompt_for_download": False,
        "disable-popup-blocking": False,
        "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0
    }
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    options.add_argument("--lang=pt-BR")
    chrome_service_obj = ChromeService(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service_obj, options=options)

    return driver


downdir_dest = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'downdir')


driver = create_webdriver_chrome(downdir_dest)
driver.get("chrome://settings/certificates")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 2)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="import"]')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()

The pages it need to open are:



See if answer to similar question can help in your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55247017/programmatically-install-an-ssl-certificate-into-a-browsers-store
